# HTML5 canvas .toDataURL() image has no background color

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

### Problem

When using `.toDataURL()` method of HTML5 `<canvas>` element the `background-color` property of the element is not applied to the picture.

### Question

Is this happenning because `background-color` is not actually a part of `canvas`, but a DOM styling? If so, or anything else, what can be a workaround for this?

### Fiddle

Fiddle to play with [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/qDmhV/158/). The base64 string is logged to console.

### Additional info

The canvas is created from the `svg` using https://code.google.com/p/canvg/

Comment: Have you tried drawing a big rectangle of the correct colour on your `canvas`?

Comment: @robertc works fine with `.drawSvg`, but no luck with `canvg()`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're correct that it isn't actually a part of the image data, only a part of the styling. The easiest way around this is to just draw a rectangle before drawing the SVG:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('test');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

Comment: Yeah, that works with `.drawSvg`, but does not with `canvg()` http://jsfiddle.net/qDmhV/159/. Any ideas why?

Comment: Try changing `ingoreClear` to `ignoreClear`. ;)

Answer (score 43):

Other approach could be creating a dummy CANVAS and copying the original CANVAS content onto it.

```
//create a dummy CANVAS

destinationCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
destinationCanvas.width = srcCanvas.width;
destinationCanvas.height = srcCanvas.height;

destCtx = destinationCanvas.getContext('2d');

//create a rectangle with the desired color
destCtx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
destCtx.fillRect(0,0,srcCanvas.width,srcCanvas.height);

//draw the original canvas onto the destination canvas
destCtx.drawImage(srcCanvas, 0, 0);

//finally use the destinationCanvas.toDataURL() method to get the desired output;
destinationCanvas.toDataURL();
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer...was struggling for such a beautiful answer...earlier answer makes the entire image white. Great job!!!

Comment: Yes, copying the source into the new canvas is definately the better solution. Thanks

Comment: Amazing solution, I was using getImageData but that doesn't work for transparent backgrounds.

Answer (score 0):

hope this will help,

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('test');

var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

//cache height and width        
var w = canvas.width;
var h = canvas.height;

var data = context.getImageData(0, 0, w, h);

var compositeOperation = context.globalCompositeOperation;

context.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-over";
context.fillStyle = "#fff";
context.fillRect(0,0,w,h);

var imageData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

context.clearRect (0,0,w,h);
context.putImageData(data, 0,0);        
context.globalCompositeOperation = compositeOperation;

var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = imageData;
a.download = 'template.png';
a.click();
```

Comment: Please provide some explanatory content along your code.

Answer (score 0):

Canvas with background color:

```
function getCanvasImageWithBackgroundColor(canvasObj, backgroundColor) {
    const combinedCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    combinedCanvas.width = canvasObj.width;
    combinedCanvas.height = canvasObj.height;
    
    const combinedCtx = combinedCanvas.getContext('2d');
    combinedCtx.fillStyle = backgroundColor;
    combinedCtx.fillRect(0, 0, canvasObj.width, canvasObj.height);
    combinedCtx.drawImage(canvasObj, 0, 0);

    return combinedCanvas.toDataURL('image/png');
}
```

Canvas with background image:

```
function getCanvasImageWithBackgroundImage(canvasObj, backgroundImage) {
    const imageObj = document.createElement("img");
    imageObj.src = backgroundImage;

    const combinedCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    combinedCanvas.width = canvasObj.width;
    combinedCanvas.height = canvasObj.height;
    
    const combinedCtx = combinedCanvas.getContext('2d');
    combinedCtx.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0, canvasObj.width, canvasObj.height);
    combinedCtx.drawImage(canvasObj, 0, 0);

    return combinedCanvas.toDataURL('image/png');
}
```